# Converted list to string returning empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x

In below code 'final' variable is producing right output but the same variable ('final') when converted to str, its giving empty list. Any idea?

Content of input file --

{"tables": ["t1", "t2", "t3"], "linkage": ["link1", "link2"],"filter": ["1=1", "filter1", "filter2"]}
{"tables": ["t4", "t5", "t6"], "linkage": ["link3", "link4"],"filter": ["filter3", "filter4", "filter5"]}

'''

```
import json
def main():

    sql = []
    status = []
    msg = []
    final = [sql,status,msg]
    final1 = str(final)   # List to string conversion

    with open("E:/hadoop/sample.txt", "r") as file:
        dict_file = file.readlines()

    def fw(**kargs):
        # Error Handling in input
        if (len(kargs['linkage']) < len(kargs['tables']) - 1):
            print('Discrepancy in number of links and tables provided')

            sql.append("None")
            status.append("Failure")
            msg.append("Discrepancy in number of links and tables provided")

        else:

            df = "select * from " + ', '.join(i for i in kargs['tables']) + " on " + ' and '.join(
                i for i in kargs['linkage']) + " where " + ' and '.join(i for i in kargs['filter'])

            sql.append(df)
            status.append("Success")
            msg.append("SQL Created Successfully")


    for lines in dict_file:
        # Convert dictionary string to dictionary
        dct = json.loads(lines)
        # Accessing dictionary elements and passing to the function
        fw(tables=dct["tables"], linkage=dct["linkage"], filter=dct["filter"])


    print(final)   
    print(final1)  # **Returning empty list**



# Executing main()
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

'''

Comment: Converting to `str` doesn't preserve references to the original lists. Move that call to the  end of your function.

Comment: Well, from what I can see, you defined `final` and `final1` at the start of the function, then modify the contents of `final`, and that should update them correctly. However, `final1` was evaluated at the beginning; it's a string, it won't change. You have to evaluate it again if you want an updated value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning, your `final` looks like this: `[[], [], []]`. At this point you are converting it to string, so `final1` gives you `[[], [], []]` as well. But after this, you are appending to the `sql`, `status`, and `msg` arrays, so by reference, you are appending to `final`. Note that this changes don't affect `final1`, because its a string without references.

You need to convert `final` to string at the and of the program, or at least after you run `fw(...)`

Answer (score 1):

At the point you are defining final1 - sql, status, msg are empty lists and final is a list containing empty lists. so `final1 = str(final)` will return the string representation of list containing empty lists.

If you want to get the final result - I suggest moving both `final` and `final1` definitions to the end of the function.